# Why can’t I login and stay logged in on Super User but can when logging into Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, windows-10, login

I have changed my password for the 10th time today on Super User.

Every time I try to login in it tells me username or password incorrect in every browser I use. I tried using the Chrome password feature so it automatically logs in but the same thing happens. Every time I open the tab again after changing my password I get logged out and have to login again which then brings me back to resetting again.

I don’t know why this happens only with Super User, with Stack Overflow this doesn’t happen.

Can anyone please help me this is frustrating. I am writing this from my phone as I cannot change the password anymore until after a few hours on web the website.

FWIW, I have Kaspersky Total Security installed and nothing else regarding security and such on the system.

Comment: Are you using Incognito or Private browsing mode? Have you disabled cookies for [su]?